# How to optimize a multiple choice setting MYSQL table schema?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am currently designing the database for my new app. Users can choose in the app if they want to get emails about specific topics. Before the system sends out emails, it must check which user subscribes to what topic. Below you can see my current table schema.

As you can subscribe to over 70 topics in the app and as there are a lot of users in the database (over 10,000), I am afraid that the table "User_Settings" could get too big over time.

Is there any more elegant solution for that?

**Click on the below numbers to see the current table schema or check the code below**

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

**Let's assume the following use case:**

There are over 70 topics and 10,000 users. Each user subscribes per default for each topic. Users unsubscribe occasionally to specific topics.

```
CREATE TABLE `users`
(
 `id`    int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE `Newsletter Settings`
(
 `id`   int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `topic_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE `user_newsletter_settings`
(
 `id`          int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `settings_id` int unsigned NOT NULL ,
 `user_id`     int unsigned NOT NULL ,
 `status`      tinyint(1) NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `to_newsletter settings` (`settings_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_89` FOREIGN KEY `to_newsletter settings` (`settings_id`) REFERENCES `Newsletter Settings` (`id`),
KEY `to_users` (`user_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_95` FOREIGN KEY `to_users` (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
```

Comment: you don't need an id in settings_users, only if you want to reference it

Comment: @nbk thank you for your tip! Which PK do you use instead?

Comment: no one, as i already wrote only when you need this id to use it in a query, but you get all users and join both tabke if you also need the other information from the other table, else the id is enough

Comment: @AlvaroPimentel Presumably a natural key exists on (settings_id,user_id), rendering the surrogate id obsolete, but some users like to have a surrogate PK anyway, and assign a composite UNIQUE key on the other columns

Comment: Is there any better approach than creating such a massive join table? Imagine you have several similar "multiple-choice settings"  and an even bigger user base  (+100,000). Wouldn't this lead to several massive queries each time you send out emails?

Comment: Change the indexes in `user_newsletter_settings` according to the these tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: @AlvaroPimentel in this case, performance isn't a big deal. let says (as some pointed out), you remove the column id. then, 10 000 users * 70 newsletter * 8 (2 * four bytes for ids), thats roughly 5megs of data.  Do proper indexing based on yours queries and you're good

Answer (score 0):

A mysql join table between users and topics to represent subscriptions is an efficient and performant mechanism to represent the relationship.  If there are hundreds of thousands or millions of subscriptions in your system, they have to go *somewhere*.  Mysql gives you a source of truth with simple and reliable consistency mechanisms to represent such a subscription's existence.

At some point, having one giant table of subscriptions would become a limiting factor.  Partitioning, sharding, or caching these subscription lists would be a logical approach to improve the scalability of this data.  But subscription relationships, if well modeled, won't be the bottleneck for a long time.

Keep in mind that rendering thousands of emails from template is much more expensive than simply obtaining the lists of thousands of intended recipients.   For that matter, sending the email (whether direct SMTP or a mail API) will incur enough latency to make the process pretty slow if executed serially.  So as you think about performance and efficiency here, don't worry overly about the subscription join table until it's slower than the email delivery engine.